# Memory Hotplug in Linux is supported?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel

Does someone know, if the underlying hardware supports memory hotplug, in Linux is supported without reboot?

Especially in Centos 6.x(x86_64).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supported in RHEL 6.x (try to use >6.0) but I would strongly urge you to install all of the drivers from your server vendor first. In HP servers this is easy and certainly 6.7 x64 works fine with this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't understand the point for installing all of the drivers from server vendor, apart from the loaded modules of the kernel what else?

Comment: Well in the HP case it adds drivers and tools for dealing with hotplug memory, hotplug CPUs, IO devices etc - not sure you'll need them but why not eh?

Comment: Ok i see. The memory will be recognized in tha OS without any action from my side?

Comment: again it depends on your vendor, you've still not mentioned who it is - not every system can do this of course - but if it's supported then it's probably supported with the latest firmware and drivers.

Comment: yes sorry i missed it, it is for hp blade proliant g460c gen8/9.

Comment: erm....how do you intend to hot-add the memory then if it's a blade??????

Comment: Sorry i thought it is possible but yes it isn't. But if it was an HP rack mounted server, in the OS would be visible after the plugging?

Comment: Yep, most DL3xx-5xx and DL980's can do that yes - not the lesser boxes though.